# make ng-click function generic to add rows

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an add row function in one of the templates(for eg section1). It currently adds a new row to the table present on the current template. I want to make this generic so that if i use this in a different template(section2, section3 and so on), it would add a row present on the table on that template.

```
$scope.section1 = [];

<button ng-click="addNewItem()">Add Row</button>

$scope.addNewItem=function(){
    $scope.section1.push('');
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then the simplest solution would simply be to pass the section into the function

For example

```
<button ng-click="addNewItem(section1)">Add Row</button>
<button ng-click="addNewItem(section2)">Add Row</button>
```

You could also achieve this by creating a custom directive but that probably isn't necessary

Comment: how would the addNewItem function look like for the while passing arguments as "section1", "section2"?

Comment: In your example $scope.section1 is simply an array so the function would be  `$scope.addNewItem=function(section){
    section.push('');
 };`